# How to properly apply dropout with train_and_evaluate function in tf.contrib.learn.Experiment

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using tensorflow high level api `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` to run my model.
I applied `tf.nn.dropout` in the model code and use `train_and_evaluate` function to train the model. However, I can't figure out know how to set argument `keep_prob` as 1 in `tf.nn.dropout` only at evaluation within `train_and_evaluate` process(because generally dropout should be used only at training).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`tf.estimator.ModeKeys`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/ModeKeys) to detect whether you are calling your estimator in TRAIN mode or in EVAL mode.

When constructing your model function for your Estimator (as depicted in this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/estimators#constructing_the_model_fn)), the function have to respect a skeleton :

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
```

The `mode` parameter is a `tf.estimator.ModeKeys`, so, in your model function, you can simply test against the `mode` parameter to detect whether you are in training or in evaluation. (or in prediction).

A simple example :

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode, params):
    keep_prob = 1.0
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        keep_prob = 0.8
    [...]
```

**On the side :**

Instead of using `tf.nn.dropout`, consider using [`tf.layers.dropout`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout). It's a wrapper over `tf.nn.dropout`, but it comes with a boolean to activate or deactivate the dropout. (You can set the boolean the same way that the prob in my example).

Comment: yeah, I did use the `tf.estimator.ModeKeys` to call my estimator. however, my TRAIN mode use the function `train_and_evaluate()` but not `train()` funtion, so I can't directly deliver my `ModeKeys` to the estimator. In this case, `tf.layer.dropout` also can't provide the solution.

Comment: What makes you think that the `train_and_evaluate` function from the Experiment don't call the `train` and `evaluate` functions from your `Estimator` ?

Comment: I didn't meant that `train_and_evaluate()` function doesn't call `train()` and `evaluate()` function. I wrote down on the last comment that : `if tf.estimator.ModeKeys == 'train' : experiment_model.train_and_evaluate()`. here `experiment_model` refer to my `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` instance. In this case, How can I control the `keep_prob` only while evaluating?

Comment: I need the `evaluation()` progress inside `train_and_evaluate()` to have `keep_prob = 1.0`

Comment: Could you  please edit your question and provide me the code you're working with ? I have trouble understanding your statements.

Comment: oops, I updated my code several months ago and i forgot that there is also `mode` argument in `model_fn`. The second time i saw your answer I found that you told me to use the `ModeKeys` inside `model_fn`. Sorry for my carelessness. Thanks.